# In Node/Express, how to match or compare values in nested promises using csv-to-array

Tags: node.js, ajax, csv, express, promise

I have a Node/Express partial that is being called with AJAX, and is supposed to send a status update back to the view, after 2 subsequent API calls are made. This workflow relies on the csv-to-array module to read a ship-orders.csv file, and determine if the second API call (POST to Shipments) has already occured. It is supposed to do this by matching the OrderNumber in the csv file to the returned OrderNumber from the FindOrders endpoint (the first API).

The problem is that I am creating 2 arrays of order numbers to compare, but matching the first set of order numbers to the second set either always returns true or always returns false, and it very clearly should show "true" for the first record in the csv, and "false" for every other.

Before getting into the bulk of the code, here's the promise that reads the csv file into an array:

**csv-to-array:**

```
var csvShipPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

    var csvColumns = ['ChannelName', 'OrderNumber', 'LineNumber', 'WarehouseCode', 'Qty', 'Carrier', 'TrackingNumber', 'Shipdate', 'ShipMethod'];
    var csvShipArr;

    var csvArr;
    csvArray({
        file: shipLog,
        columns: csvColumns
    }, function(err, array){
        csvShipArr = array;
        resolve(csvShipArr);
    });
});
```

Next I have a long promise that gets executed when the request to the partial is made. The comparison between logged OrderNumbers and OrderNumbers that need to be posted to Shipments is the 5th "then" block (and it's commented in the code below).

**router.get and chained promise:**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

findPromise.then(function(findData){
    //Properly format xml string
    var foundData = replaceAll(findData, '&lt;', '<');
        foundData = replaceAll(foundData, '&gt;', '>');
    return foundData;  
}).then(function(foundData){
    //Parse xml to JSON and stringify
    var parsedFound;
    parseString(foundData, function(err, result){  //uses an xml to json module
       parsedFound = JSON.stringify(result); 
    });
    return(parsedFound);
}).then(function(parsedStr){
    //Parse JSON and return an array of objects
    var parsedJson = JSON.parse(parsedStr);
    var orders = parsedJson['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body'][0]['FindOrders'][0]['orders'][0]['order'];
    return orders;
}).then(function(orders){
    //Get only orders with a tracking number.
    var trackArray = [];
    var ord;
    for(ord in orders){
        var postObj = orders[ord];
        if(postObj.TrackingNumber[0].length > 1){
            trackArray.push(postObj);
        }
    }
    return trackArray;  //array of orders that contain tracking numbers
}).then(function(trackArray){

    /**** This is the block that is causing problems. *****/

    var tItm;

    var loggedOrders = [];
    for(tItm in trackArray){
        var alreadyLogged = false;
        var trackedItm = trackArray[tItm];
        var trackedOrderNum = trackedItm.ReferenceNum;
        csvShipPromise.then(function(csvOrders){
            var csv;
            var loggedOrderArr = [];
            for (csv in csvOrders){
                var csvItm = csvOrders[csv];
                var csvOrderNum = csvItm.OrderNumber; //gets the OrderNumber as expected
                loggedOrderArr.push(csvOrderNum);
            }
            return loggedOrderArr; //Return a simple array of all OrderNumbers
        }).then(function(loggedOrderArr){
            console.log(loggedOrderArr);
            console.log(trackedOrderNum);
            var ord;
            for (ord in loggedOrderArr){
                if(trackedOrderNum == loggedOrderArr[ord]){
                    console.log('found');
                    alreadyLogged = true;
                }
                else {
                    console.log('not found');
                    alreadyLogged = false;
                }
            }
            return loggedOrderArr; //Simply returning this value because the alreadyLogged test isn't working.
        });

        /*  Here is where the test fails.
          It shouldn't, because there are, say, 4 OrderNumbers in the result of the first API call,
          and only 1 Order number logged in the CSV.
          So it should be true once, and false 3 times.
          But it is true all the time.
        */
        if(alreadyLogged){
            console.log('found');  //Always logs true/found.
        } else {
            console.log('not found');
        }
    }
    return trackArray; //Just passing the array to the view, for now.
}).then(function(obj){
    res.send(obj);
    return(obj);
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
});
```

When I console.log the values of trackArray and loggedOrderArr, I see that there should be an intersection between an array of 4 values and an array of 1 value, but for some reason the comparison, `if(trackedOrderNumber == loggedOrderArr[ord])` isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I'm gonna be honest, your code made my eyes swim. but as far as I can tell, a few things pop up:

- move var `alreadyLogged = false;` to before the loop;
- then add `alreadyLogged = false;` after `if(alreadyLogged)` statement

I think it has to do with scope. You are basically checking bool value of a var that has not changed yet because your promises has not resolved at the point of `if(alreadyLogged)`

Might I suggest a different approach?

why not make use of array.indexOf() ?

lets say you have two arrays to compare arrA & arrB; you can see if an item exists like so:

```
var index = arrA.indexOf(arrB[0]); 
if(index == -1){
   console.log('No Match');
}
else{
   console.log('Match found');
}
```

no need for any preset flags to see if one array contains an element.

Hope it helps.

A bit more context:

```
var index = loggedOrderArray.indexOf(trackedOrderNum); 
if(index == -1){
   console.log('No Match');
   // -1 basicaly means that there is not instance of trackedOrderNum in loggedOrderArray
}
else{
   console.log('Match found');
}
```

Comment: It's Node. We've got ES2016 there. `if(loggedOrderArray.includes(trackedOrderNum)) ...`

Comment: This was definitely the most helpful. I think it was some sort of scope problem. What I did to correctly log the comparison was move the comparison to an separate function. Only then did the script log either "found" or "not found." Curiously, when I put the same process from the function back into the chained promise, only the true case, "found," was logged to the console.

Comment: ** Working Comparison Function: **
`function compareOrders(trackNum){
    csvShipPromise.then(function(csvOrders){
        var csv;
        for (csv in csvOrders){
            var csvItm = csvOrders[csv];
            var csvOrderNum = csvItm.OrderNumber;
                if(compareOrderNumbers(csvOrderNum, trackNum)){
                    console.log('found csvOrderNum');
                } else {
                    console.log('This was not found');
                }
        }
    });
}`

Answer (score 1):

What you are attempting appears to be reasonably simple. You are just overwhelming yourself with awkward flow control and bulky code.

As it stands, asynchronous flow isn't quite right chiefly due to `parseString()` not being promisified. A value returned from a raw nodeback won't propagate down a .then chain.

In addition, asynchronous flow will improve with :

- application of `Promise.all()` up front to aggregate the two essential data-delivering promises `csvShipPromise` and `findPromise`.
- the realisation that wholly synchronous steps in a promise chain can be merged with next step.

And, the bulk of the synchronous code will reduce by employing several Array methods:

- [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Boiling it down to somewhere near the bare minimum, I get the following `router.get()` expression:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    return Promise.all([csvShipPromise, findPromise])
    .then([csvOrders, findData] => { // destructuring
        let loggedOrderArr = csvOrders.map(order => order.OrderNumber);
        let foundData = replaceAll(findData, '&lt;', '<');
            foundData = replaceAll(foundData, '&gt;', '>');
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // promisify parseString() on the fly
            parseString(foundData, (err, result) => {
                if(err) reject(err);
                else resolve(result['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body'][0].FindOrders[0].orders[0].order); // does this expression really return `orders` (plural)?
            });
        })
        .then(orders => {
            let trackArray = orders.filter(postObj => postObj.TrackingNumber[0].length > 1); // filter orders to eliminate those without a tracking number.
            let loggedOrders = trackArray.filter(trackedItm => loggedOrderArr.includes(trackedItm.ReferenceNum));
            // let unloggedOrders = trackArray.filter(trackedItm => !loggedOrderArr.includes(trackedItm.ReferenceNum));
            res.send(loggedOrders); // or res.send(unloggedOrders), depending on what you want.
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.error(err); // or similar
    });
});
```

*untested - I may have made mistakes, though hopefully ones that are simple to correct*